# Truffle Test - Solidity: How to access value of Promise object? [object Promise] [BigNumber]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, truffle-test, bignumber

```
a.getB.call().then(function (f) { console.log(f[1][0]) });
```

outputs:

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 20, c: [ 5000000 ] }
```

How can I access the value in c?

How can I save object f to a javascript variable?

Since I am saving an array of arrays, can I get the length of the Promise object?

Comment: `f.toString()` check BigNumber library also https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually added another question which is kind of related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I access the value in c?

the number is not *only* what is contained inside `c` but the whole BigNumber notation, which is accessible with a `f.toString()`

> How can I save object f to a javascript variable?

`f.toString()` will give you a string, which can be saved into a variable. Same as you can keep it inside the `BigNumber` object and use the `.toString` to access to a readable value

> Since I am saving an array of arrays, can I get the length of the Promise object?

this question doesn't make sense given the answers above, that kind of structure is the internal representation of the number stored into the `BigNumber` object

Comment: `var b;
  a.getB.call().then(function (f) { b = f });
  console.log('b: ' + b);`
outputs: `b: undefined`

Comment: that's because the function inside `then` is not executed yet. console.log will be printed before `b` will be assigned

Comment: Seems correct. Fixed it with `var b; await a.getB.call().then(function (f) { b = f }); console.log('b: ' + b);` Thanks!